# Display results of query in user admin section - django

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

Newbie question:

I have my "users" app in the django admin but is there a way to implement a section that only shows users with criteria is_staff = False or any other criteria that I define?
I'm a bit lost because I don't think it's necessary to create an app, because I don't need to create a new table, just query and display.

For example:

[image]

My query should I implement it in users / admin.py? But how do I render the result of the query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can define filters in the admin class. Then Django automatically creates a filter sidebar where you can filter the users.

```
@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    model = User
    list_filter = ('is_staff', )
```

For more information please look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `get_queryset` method from `UserAdmin` class with whatever request you want on your `User` table. For example, in your `admin.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    model = User

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(is_staff=False)
```

You can even use some current user's attributes to request the data depending on it, like:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super().get_queryset(request)
    if not request.user.is_staff:
        return qs.filter(is_staff=False)
    return qs
```